# Using LinkedList iterator not working in this case

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, iterator

Here I have the code that contains only one method that has 2 parameters. First one is of type linkedlist and second one is of type String. The idea here is that I call this function from the main method several time and each new item that gets added should be sorted from A-Z. But for some reason if I don't add return in the function (

```
 else if(compareResult>0) {
                iterator.previous();
                iterator.add(element);
                return;
            }
```

)

then I get empty list printed out. Why is that?

````
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<String> list=new LinkedList<>();

            addAndSortElements(list,"a");
        addAndSortElements(list,"b");
        addAndSortElements(list,"c");
        addAndSortElements(list,"f");
        addAndSortElements(list,"d");
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    private static void addAndSortElements(LinkedList<String> linkedList, String element) {

        var iterator= linkedList.listIterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            String editedElement=element.toLowerCase();
            int compareResult=iterator.next().toLowerCase().compareTo(editedElement);

            if(compareResult==0) {
                System.out.println("Element is already on the list");
                ***return;***
            }
            else if(compareResult>0) {
                iterator.previous();
                iterator.add(element);
                return;
            }
            else {

            }
        }
        iterator.add(element);
    }
}

```
`

I have tried everything I said above.
````

Comment: You shouldn't get an empty list just by not adding a `return` statement - unless I missed something. Are you sure you're not rather running into some endless loop, e.g. by constantly calling `next()` and `previous()`, and thus nothing is printed? In general it is good practice to leave a method once it's done (i.e. in your case once the element has been added or a duplicate has been found) so the `return;` isn't that bad.

Comment: Btw, I assume you have `iterator.add(element);` twice to catch the special case of the element being added to the end (or an empty list) in which case having `return` after adding the element in other places is necessary as not to add the element twice.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer there's `System.out.println(list);` in the main method :)

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer I am printing it in the main method

Comment: But still, without return keyword list is empty and program is not looping forever...so why isn't it working?

Comment: @Thomas thank you but still I don't know why isn't it working.

Comment: If what you're executing is the code you've posted the list should at least have element "a" since in that case `iterator.hasNext()` should return `false` and thus `iterator.add(element);` would be called. Did you try with only adding "a"? If that works the other calls should at least keep the "a" in the list as there's no code that would remove anything from the list. If that doesn't work I'd suspect one of 2 things: 1) this isn't the code you're running or 2) you get an endless loop without realizing it.

Comment: Reasoning through the code I'd say it runs fine until you're trying to add "d". Eventually `next()` returns "f" and thus you're calling `previous()` and `add()`. `previous()` sets the iterator's cursor back to between "f" and "c" and thus `next()` would return "f" again. Now you're adding "d" but this doesn't change the result of `next()` (see JavaDoc on `add()`) and thus you get "f" again, call `previous()` again, add "d" again etc. etc. - here's the endless loop which you basically get out of with the `return` after adding "d" the first time. - Update: tested and confirmed the endless loop.

Comment: @Thomas you were right. It is an endless loop without return statement.

Comment: As a side note, you should simply call [`compareToIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) instead of converting every string to a lowercase string before comparing. Not only will this handle special Unicode scenarios correctly, it’s far more efficient (a comparison stops at the first mismatching character, while a to-lowercase conversion processes the entire string even before the comparison started).